# numpy nonzero() returns indexes sorted by row index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

As in Matlab, the [`nonzeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) return the indexes ordered by columns. In `NumPy`, it seems the returned indexes are ordered by rows (for a `2D` matrix). But this is not articulated in its [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

So, is it safe to assume that?

An example:

```
test = np.array([[0,2], [3,0]])
test[test.nonzero()]
```

gives `array([2, 3])` instead of `array([3, 2])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the following comment [on the C source code of `PyArray_NonZero`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.10.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2162), the C function that handles all the calls to `nonzero`:

```
/*NUMPY_API
 * Nonzero
 *
 * TODO: In NumPy 2.0, should make the iteration order a parameter.
 */
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyObject *
PyArray_Nonzero(PyArrayObject *self)
```

The iteration order [is now hardcoded to be C-order](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.10.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2267), i.e. last index varies the fastest, i.e. sorted rows, then columns, for the 2D case. Given that comment, it is very safe to assume that, if this ever changes, it will be by providing new functionality that defaults to the current behavior.

Comment: Probably this is better articulated in the comment numpy nonzero function, i.e. its api doc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, numpy arrays work with rows then column indexes. If you want to work in a more Matlab way then you work with a transposed array. eg.

```
test.T[test.T.nonzero()]
```

The `T` property gives a transposed *view* of your array. So rows become columns and columns become rows. And because the array is a view, rather than a copy, it's also a very cheap operation.